# How to use <Note> for annotation for react-pdf?

Tags: reactjs, react-pdf, react-pdfrenderer, react-pdf-viewer

I use react-pdf of `https://react-pdf.org` to create and display my pdf file.
However, a new requirement needs to use annotation, and I believe `<Note></Note>` is for annotation but I can't find sample on how to use it.
I tried using it by placing it inside the `<View><View>` but an error shows up saying `No PDF file specified`.